# Wondering what "establish facts on the ground" means in this piece of news

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Kerry said he had been clear with Lavrov about the consequences “if Russia doesn’t find a way to change course.” This, Kerry explained, was not a threat but would be a “consequence” of choices Russia may or may not make.
>
> He added that if Russia does **establish facts on the ground** that threaten the Ukrainian people, it “will beg an even greater cost”. 
> <sub>Source: [euronews – *‘US will not recognise the result of the referendum on Crimea’, says John Kerry*](http://www.euronews.com/2014/03/14/us-will-not-recognise-the-result-of-the-referendum-on-crimea-says-john-kerry/)</sub>

Can this be rewritten in simpler English?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a bit obscure, and intentionally so.  It's the sort of thing that politicians and diplomats say when they want to avoid saying anything too confrontational.

"Facts on the ground" is diplomatic language for verifiable facts as opposed to conjecture.  So, if Russia does something tangible to harm the Ukranians, such as invade with the forces they have deployed at the border, then the action in and of itself will "beg" for a greater consequence than those currently being contemplated.

An undiplomatic approximation would be "If Russia does anything to harm the Ukrainians, they will be asking for more trouble than they are in already."

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning the phrase's similarity to [“boots on the ground”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boots_on_the_ground) which I think might be relevant to the implied message (which you've summarized well here).

Comment: Yes, that sounds like where the term derives from.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the 2 ways borders can be drawn:

1. Discuss them at a roundtable with your neighbours.
2. Send soldiers ("boots on the ground") to where you say the border is, create tollhouses at the border, tax people inside your borders, etc. Once you've done that work on the ground, the border is a fact. In this case you "established facts on the ground". These are usually unilateral actions which do affect others, create a new status quo, and almost always involve troops of some kind.

This doesn't have to be limited to borders.

Answer (score 0):

Diplomatic way -

> He added that if Russia does establish [facts on the ground](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facts_on_the_ground) that threaten the Ukrainian people, it “will beg an even greater cost”.

Simpler English as you asked -

> Russia, stop doing this further or else you'll have to pay a lot for it.